# Increase OWIN user login time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, owin

I create a project in asp .net mvc 5 with default `OWIN` authentication with users and roles tables. when a user logs in the default timeout is **5 minutes** and **after 5 minutes user logout and redirect to login page**. How can I increase this time from 5 minutes to 24 hours.

I try these codes but didn't work:

```
ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24),
SlidingExpiration = true
```

this is a part of my project's `web.config` file:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: can you show more of your cookie settings and login method?

Comment: @Shoe when create a new project in visual studio I select Authentication type as Indivisual User Accounts. Where is cookie settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this tag to `<system.web>` and the problem is solved:

```
<machineKey validationKey="7DB9F31CBC3B6059038DF7212AD3A01E34C64A0883E05A0987EC697E659FFC58FBE36BDA98185DA62555690CD8C286C6752D6BFAB0C3519DE777A7EFCD21984D" decryptionKey="7908EB5206AB8C410BC2117F2778C7D24EDC2537739449A272CD4DDBB1116E13" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Generate your own machine key using this website:

http://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this key to your web.config

```
<system.web> <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1440" /> </system.web>
```